Excel: Can you combine the reference saving of both CUT and COPY
As a quick summary, here is my understanding of the differences between the current implementations of CUT and COPY (non-exhaustive):
CUT:
 • Maintains all references into and out of the cut region (does not breaking any formulas inside the CUT region), but
• Breaks all the formulas that reference your target cells (that you cut to), giving a #REF error.
COPY:
 • Breaks all references into and out of the cut region that are not absolute references (with $'s), but
• Maintains the formulas pointing at the target cells.
What I would like to do is keep both of the MAINTAINS from CUT and COPY, ie, I want to save all the references as-is inside the cut region, and also do not break all the cells that reference the target region. So for a copy-paste, it will act like CUT for copying the data (save the from references) and act like COPY when pasting the data (save the to references).
Common suggestions online include PASTE-SPECIAL, but that does not allow any kind of CUT-ness, it's just deciding what to copy, which we've already identified as breaking non-absolute references (none of the special options fixes this, I wish it did, that could be an actual solution to my request). Another common suggestion is to make everything absolute references and then copy, but this removes any ability to edit and update those same cells (and isn't easy to do anyways), as everything is absolute, no dragging or updating of formulas or cells would be possible without un-absoluting everything, or updating each cell individually (which breaks half the purpose of using a spreadsheet). If there was a way to just do a temporary absolute reference, that vanishes after 1 copy, or a way to put in a character that I can easily take out later on, that would also work.
Unfortunately, I suspect this is simply not possible. Open to suggestions.
